# SQL unable to add numeric column alias to another column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a column alias '10%' to a column InvoiceTotal but it states that the column name '10%' does not exist
if I remove ([10%] + InvoiceTotal) AS [Plus 10%], the results will have the column 10%.
what am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT InvoiceTotal, (InvoiceTotal * .10) AS [10%], ([10%] + InvoiceTotal) AS [Plus 10%]
FROM Invoices    
WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 500
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias does not exist until the query is complete, and you're trying to use it before that point.

The fix is pretty easy, though - just don't use the alias. :-)

```
SELECT 
  InvoiceTotal, 
  InvoiceTotal * .10 AS [10%], 
  InvoiceTotal + (InvoiceTotal * .10) AS [Plus 10%]
FROM 
  Invoices    
WHERE 
  InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 500
ORDER BY 
  InvoiceTotal DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1:

```
SELECT src.*, src.[10%], (src.[10%] + src.InvoiceTotal) AS [Plus 10%]
FROM
(
    SELECT InvoiceTotal, (InvoiceTotal * .10) AS [10%]
    FROM Invoices    
    WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 500
) src
ORDER BY src.InvoiceTotal DESC;
```

Solution #2:

```
;WITH BaseQuery
AS
(
    SELECT InvoiceTotal, (InvoiceTotal * .10) AS [10%]
    FROM Invoices    
    WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 500
)
SELECT src.*, src.[10%], (src.[10%] + src.InvoiceTotal) AS [Plus 10%]
FROM BaseQuery src
ORDER BY src.InvoiceTotal DESC;
```

Solution #3:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceTotal, x.[10%], (x.[10%] + i.InvoiceTotal) AS [Plus 10%]
FROM Invoices i   
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT (i.InvoiceTotal * .10) AS [10%] ) x
WHERE i.InvoiceTotal - i.PaymentTotal - i.CreditTotal > 500
ORDER BY i.InvoiceTotal DESC;
```